# Question maybe related to windows security

Tags: windows, security

Is there any ***quick-to-grasp*** article about the concepts such as "Windows Session", "token", "Windows identity", "impersonation", "default computer account", etc.

I want to know how different types of applications run on windows in different sessions with different identities. (Hope I make myself clear.)

Many thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the following article on impersonation:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2005/03/21/400088.aspx

Here is some great C# code dealing with impersonation:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saurabhkv/archive/2008/05/29/windowsidentity-impersonation-using-c-code.aspx

Additional code dealing with impersonation given a token:

http://alt.pluralsight.com/wiki/default.aspx/Keith.GuideBook/HowToImpersonateAUserGivenHerToken.html

Comment: Thanks Michael. I will read these materials and post some feedbacks.